# ReSharper Replace All Method Implementations with NotImplementedException

Tags: refactoring, resharper, automated-refactoring, resharper-9.0, notimplementedexception

I have a huge library of classes I copied and I want to set all methods in all classes to:

```
throw new NotImplementedException();
```

Does ReSharper have a way to do this globally over the whole solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using ReSharper's Search with Pattern feature in semi-automatic way, i would say. I'll better attach screenshot.

[image]

This way you replace all private instance methods in Solution. Then you need to replace all public, protected, internal, same with static and virtual keywords and you'll be there.